# Scanner for uncut medium format film?

Tags: scanning, medium-format

I have a couple rolls of medium format slide film from my holga. I was playing with the thing, shooting images without worrying about the frames. So, the whole film is one series of overlapping images without any frame distinctions.

I was wondering if there is a scanner that could scan all ~3 feet of the color positive film. I could try to make judicious cuts and then stitch it back up on the computer, but I'd rather not.

The scanner I have currently is an Epson Perfection V600. It has an adapter for taking medium format, but it's only large enough to accept 3 full frames: [image: film too long]

If I try to slip the film into the scanner without the adapter, the scanner reports and error and refuses to scan: [image: too long for scanner]

So, I wonder if there is a scanner where I can feed through this 3 feet of medium format negative without cutting it.

Comment: What scanners did you find till now and what features exactly were they missing to let you do what you need?

Comment: @Dragos I updated the question with pictures and explanations.

Comment: I have the same question. I have cutting my negatives and Epson scanners won't do their job unless the film is cut... Super annoying.

Comment: https://www.scanace.com/scan_pd_1.php?id=8

Answer (score 1):

Do you usually scan your own medium format film? If so, just scan this roll as normal. You don't have distinct frames, so just scan sections of the roll as separate files until you have the entire roll digitised. Then use [image stitching software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_stitching) to digitally stitch the sections back together.

I am presuming that you can use a scanner whose medium format film holder will accept an uncut roll. I know my old flatbed scanner with transparency adapter allows this.

Comment: Can you link to the model of the scanner that will accept an uncut roll? I've posted pictures to my question showing that my scanner won't work like that.

Comment: Years ago I bought an Epson Perfection 1240U flatbed scanner with transparency adapter. To use its medium format holder, you slide the film into the holder, and lay the holder down on the scanner platen. It doesn't matter if there's a trail of film coming out of the holder, it still works. I'm not familiar with the V600, but I just took a look at a YouTube video and it seems the holder clicks closed around the film strip, so you can't have a trail of film coming out of the holder? Maybe try to find a third-party film holder that allows film to trail out of the holder.

Comment: https://www.scanace.com/scan_pd_1.php?id=8